# Error setting Name property of a local class in WPF DesignData file

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have this DesignData file (compilation type set to DesignData) in a XAML file:

```
<local:FooModel xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject" 
    Name="Sample" FullPath="C:/www" />
```

I have `FooModel` class inside `MyProject` namespace with those two Properties. I am getting the "Name" property in XAML underlined with red and this message:

> Error 1 Because 'microsoft.expression.markup.semantics.metadata.reflectiontypenode' is
>   implemented in the same assembly, you must set the x:Name attribute
>   rather than the microsoft.expression.markup.semantics.metadata.ReflectionPropertyNode
>   attribute.

I think the property `Name` is confused with something else. I am referring to the Property of my `FooModel` class, not anything else. I get no warnings for `FullPath`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unable to repro this. Have a similar DesignData file, with no problems at all, including a 'Name' property. Very you don't have a typo. Verify 'Custom Tool' and 'Custom Tool Namespace' are blank. I also suspect you have a weird assembly in your 'References' list. Where did you get the MS.Internal.Design... ? (was the project originated in Blend?). In a standard VS created project, this namespace doesn't appear on any of my assemblies. Check out which assembly implements this namespace, and try to remove it from the list of references.

Comment: Sorry, it actually says `microsoft.expression.markup.semantics.metadata.reflectiontypenode`, I foolishly googled and copied some other assembly string that was different :). I have nothing special in References except `Microsoft.Windows.Shell`. I can compile and run the program and everything works fine, I just get this warning/info when I hover the `Name` attribute... I tried closing and reopening the solution without difference.

Comment: How do I do "Check out which assembly implements this namespace"?

Comment: @rFactor - potentially, different class from same namespace may be implemented in different assemblies. Just select a type from the namespace (e.g. microsoft.expression...reflectiontypenode in your case) and put it on any *.cs file. If you are referencing this type, hit F12. That will take you to the "source" of the class (generated from metadata). At the top of the file, there is the Assembly it is coming from. Let me know - because in my project, I don't have expression at all (probably you started the project with blend).

Comment: This error seems to be intermittent for me. Sometimes it will be an error and upon recompile, it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I met this same error. The error disappears for a while after rebuilding the solution but it reappears after opening the corresponding DesignData file in Visual Studio (VS Professional, Version 11.0.51106.01 Update 1).

I tried removing referenced assemblies and emptied 'Custom Tool' and 'Custom Tool Namespace' values for that DesignData file. None of that helped. Pressing F12 within xaml file doesn't take me anywhere, it works only on .cs files for me.

**My Solution**

I got rid of this annoying error by referencing the property in it's complete namespace:classname.propertyname form in a separate xml element dedicated to it (instead of referencing it within xml attribute of the parent class). In your case that would mean:

```
<local:FooModel xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject" FullPath="C:/www" >
    <local:FooModel.Name>Sample</local:FooModel.Name>
</local:FooModel>
```